# Convert time elapsed from different (relative) starting points to time elapsed from zero

Tags: r

I have a vector representing seconds (1:60):

```
x <- c(3, 8, 12, 18, 25, 58, 4, 25, 44, 59, 8)
```

Seconds `3` to `58` are the number of seconds *elapsed from `0`*. The second set of seconds, `4` to `59`, represents seconds *elapsed from `58` seconds*, i.e. the last time registered in the previous chunk. E.g. the `4` means `4` seconds elapsed from `58`, and similarly for `25-59`. The last `8` represents seconds *elapsed from `59`*.

I want to convert these time in seconds from various reference points, so they instead all represent absolute number of seconds elapsed from `0`:

```
y <- c(3, 8, 12, 18, 25, 58, 62, 83, 102, 117, 125)
```

Where we sum up the 6th and 7th element (58 + 4), and 10th and 11th element (59 + 8), and even more (each near to 60 or even 60) element and get each differences of two elements. For example difference between 4 and 25 is 21. The 21 should added to 62 and results in y as 83.

Perhaps there is a solution with POSIX or CHRON, but I could not find a function to solve this problem.

Comment: No @李哲源ZheyuanLi  He wants to treat the 4 as 64.  The minute has rolled over.

Comment: In your example,  you suggest 4 should be changed to 64,  but how do you know it is not 124 or 184?

Comment: Yes the minute has rolled over. So it should be four seconds later than 58 seconds. So, 62 seconds or 1 minute and 2 seconds

Comment: Do you mean 4  seconds later than the 58  or 4 seconds after the new minute  64 seconds?

Comment: actually 4 seconds later than 58 seconds, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative. Slightly more convoluted, but seems to give the desired result.

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(x)
```

Create a grouping variable 'm', the corresponding minute *as if* each group of seconds start on the dot minute mark:

```
d[ , m := c(0, cumsum(diff(x) < 1))]
```

Calculate a new seconds variable, again *as if* each group of seconds start on the dot minute mark. For example, the `4` in the second run of seconds here tentatively correspond to 1 minute and **4** seconds, 64 s.

```
d[ , x2 := x + 60 * m]
```

However, the seconds within each "minute" are not relative to the 'within-group minute', but relative to the seconds of the last registration in the previous minute. Therefore we need to calculate number of seconds left to whole minute from the last registration within each minute:

```
d2 <- d[ , .(dif = x[.N] - 60), by = m]
```

To align adjustments with the correct minute, shift them forward. Set the adjustment in the first minute to `0`. Calculate the cumulative number of seconds to adjust within each minute:

```
d2[ , adj := cumsum(shift(dif, fill = 0))]
```

Join original data and adjustment data, a do the actual adjustment in one go using `by = .EACHI`:

```
d[d2, .(s = x2 + adj), on = "m", by = .EACHI]    
#     m   s
# 1:  0   3
# 2:  0   8
# 3:  0  12
# 4:  0  18
# 5:  0  25
# 6:  0  58
# 7:  1  62
# 8:  1  83
# 9:  1 102
# 10: 1 117
# 11: 2 125
```

I'm sure this can be simplified.

Comment: Works fine perfect! Thanks